# Simple two way binding not working in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

Ok so for some reason this really simple example doesn't work and I'm absolutely clueless as to why it doesn't work.. When I type into the textbox, nothing happens! what is even going on?!

code-behind:

```
public partial class ucTest : UserControl {
    public ucTest() {
        InitializeComponent();
        (Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }

    public string SomeText {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomeTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SomeText",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ucTest),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string)));
}
```

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PlainWPFTests.ucTest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: _"I type into the textbox, nothing happens!"_ -- please be more specific. Surely it's not true that _literally nothing_ happens. Do the characters you type appear in the `TextBox`? What _did_ you expect to happen? Is this simply a matter of you forgetting to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`? Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and of course a clear, detailed explanation of what that problem is, it's impossible to know for sure what the answer to that problem actually is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho How is this not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? and what do you expect to happen? like we're speaking about a grid, a textblock and a textbox... obviously the textblock isn't being updated when typing in the textbox.

Comment: _"How is this not a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?"_ -- in a variety of ways. Read [mcve]. It will explain what is meant by MCVE and why it's important to provide. Read also [ask], including the articles linked at the bottom of that page. Your code is trivially proved to not be an MCVE, because `UserControl` objects don't stand on their own. A WPF MCVE will necessarily always include a `Window` object as well. _"what do you expect to happen?"_ -- why should I expect anything? SO isn't a guessing game. You tell _us_ what _you_ expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: _"obviously the textblock isn't being updated when typing in the textbox"_ -- it is neither obvious that's what's happening (or not happening), nor is it obvious that that behavior is the _problem_ you are trying to fix. That said, if that is the problem you are having, then the marked duplicate has the answer to your question. You simply forgot to declare the binding correctly.